# JAXB not mapping an attribute into a "custom" class

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm generating java classes from an xml schema, and for one complex type I want jaxb to use an existing class, for which I have an external bindings customisation file.
The custom class is unmarshalled into correctly *except* for the single attribute of the type, which is never populated in the java class.

Below is a demo of the problem with type/class Thing.

The Thing as defined in the schema is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Thing">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="nameEl" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="nameAttr" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and the snippet that reads the matching xml file is:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("jaxbtest");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

// Make it validate against the instance schema
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("./sample.xsd"));
u.setSchema(schema);

Config config = (Config)u.unmarshal(new File("./sample.xml"));

for (Thing thing : config.getThing()) {
  System.out.println("nameAttr=[" + thing.getNameAttr() +"]");
  System.out.println("nameEl=[" + thing.getNameEl() +"]");
}
```

Reading in this xml:

```
<m:config xmlns:m="test">
  <thing nameAttr="hello">
    <nameEl>goodbye</nameEl>
  </thing>
</m:config>
```

using the Thing class generated by JAXB (not using the customisations xjb) the output is as expected:

```
nameAttr=[hello]
nameEl=[goodbye]
```

Using the custom Thing class which just has getters & setters for nameAttr & nameEl, the output is

```
nameAttr=[null]
nameEl=[goodbye]
```

The custom class is simply:

```
public class Thing {
    private String nameEl;
    private String nameAttr;

    public String getNameEl() {
        return nameEl;
    }
    public void setNameEl(String value) {
        this.nameEl = value;
    }

    public String getNameAttr() {
        return nameAttr;
    }
    public void setNameAttr(String value) {
        this.nameAttr = value;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the behaviour is different for the "nameEL" element and the "nameAttr" attribute" ?

Comparing the custom Thing with the JAXB generated Thing the only difference is the annotations, which I thought weren't necessary when not generating the schema from the Java classes, and clearly aren't for the contained elements.

For completeness, the xjb is:

```
<jxb:bindings
    version="2.1"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">

  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="sample.xsd">

    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='Thing']">
      <jxb:package name=""/>
      <jxb:class ref="custom.Thing"/>
    </jxb:bindings>

  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, you should be actually getting `null` in the attribute, not in the element.

My guess is that the problem is simple. Annotations ARE significant: if you don't provide them then your properties are treated as `@XmlElement`-annotated by default. This is why one property is unmarshalled and the other is not.

But, as mentioned, you should actually get `null` for the attribute, not for the element. Could you please recheck?

Here's a [relevant post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html) by Blaise.

Comment: It is the attribute that I'm getting null for.
You're right, adding the annotation into the custom class did the trick.

Comment: I'd misunderstood the nature of the xsd->java class generation mapping: I'd thought the point of defining the mappings in an .xjb would avoid editing either the xsd or the target custom java class, neither of which should need to know about the other, ie. good decoupling.  Out of interest, is there an alternative mechanism to implement the mapping to the custom class? Would this be Adapters?
PS - thanks for taking the trouble to answer my original question.